# Как заменить слова(str) в выражении через регулярные в числа(number)?

Tags: javascript

Помогите подкорректировать, если например 'thirty one' оно выдает '30 1', а нужно '31' и т.д.

```js
var strr = "thirty one";

var dictionary = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4,
    five: 5,
    six: 6,
    seven: 7,
    eight: 8,
    nine: 9,
    ten: 10,
    eleven: 11,
    twelve: 12,
    thirteen: 13,
    fourteen: 14,
    fifteen: 15,
    sixteen: 16,
    seventeen: 17,
    eighteen: 18,
    nineteen: 19,
    twenty: 20,
    thirty: 30,
    forty: 40,
    fifty: 50,
    sixty: 60,
    seventy: 70,
    eighty: 80,
    ninety: 90,
    hundred: 100
  },
  regexp = RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(dictionary).join("|") + ')\\b', 'g');
strr = strr.replace(regexp, function(_, word) {
  return dictionary[word];
});
console.log(strr); // 30 1
```

Comment: одним replace не обойтись. после замены нужно разбить строку по пробелу и свернуть полученную коллекцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что пришло в голову это заменить пробелы на знак плюс **+** чтобы получить выражение и сложить числа.

Затем выполнить выражение функцией `eval()`

```js
    var strr = "hundred thirty one";

    var dictionary = {
            one: 1,
            two: 2,
            three: 3,
            four: 4,
            five: 5,
            six: 6,
            seven: 7,
            eight: 8,
            nine: 9,
            ten: 10,
            eleven: 11,
            twelve: 12,
            thirteen: 13,
            fourteen: 14,
            fifteen: 15,
            sixteen: 16,
            seventeen: 17,
            eighteen: 18,
            nineteen: 19,
            twenty: 20,
            thirty: 30,
            forty: 40,
            fifty: 50,
            sixty: 60,
            seventy: 70,
            eighty: 80,
            ninety: 90,
            hundred: 100
        },
        regexp = RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(dictionary).join("|") + ')\\b', 'g');


    strr = strr.replace(regexp, function (_, word) {
        return dictionary[word];
    });

    strr = strr.replace(/ /g, '+');

    console.log(eval(strr)); // 131
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать разбивать по пробелам и суммировать. Ещё мы должны учитывать случай 'two hundred', например, когда мы должны не суммировать, а умножать:

```
const parseNumber = strr => strr.split(' ').reduce((sum, num, i, arr) => {
    if (arr[i + 1] === '100') return sum + (num * 100);
    if (num === '100') return sum;
    return sum + +num; 
  }, 0);
```